# jQuery Mobile Router doesn't route the first page load

Tags: jquery-mobile, router

I am using jQuery Mobile Router in a multi page setup.

For some reason, the first page load isn't handled the way it should. I have a first page that jQuery Mobile uses as default page, but even if the user includes a hash that should trigger another route, it isn't caught by the router.

The only way I've been able to resolve the issue, is by using this ugly hack:

```
$(document).one('pagebeforechange', function(event, data) {
    data.toPage = window.location.hash
});
```

I am clearly doing something wrong, but where?

The include order is: jQuery Mobile Router, jQuery Mobile and then my custom router setup.

This didn't help, so I tried setting `autoInitialize` to `false` as described in [issue 12](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router/issues/12#issuecomment-8891981) on jQuery Mobile Routers issue tracker. That didn't help either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by "multipage setup"? Single file with multiple embedded pages or separate files with a page each?

Comment: A single page with multiple embedded pages. Sorry.